# foobar2000: query if specific files exist in track's directory

Tags: filesystems, mp3, foobar2000, query

In my library there are files like .lrc files (Lyrics) or album art files (various .jpg files) next to the music files:

[image: folder with mp3, image and lyric files]

I am trying to create a autoplaylist where I want to list tracks which have a fitting .lrc file inside the same folder (like "09_Amsterdam.lrc" next to a "09_Amsterdam.mp3"). 
Or another example: filter all tracks where a "cover.jpg" does not exist in the same directory.

Is something like this possible? Like querying contents of tags?